# Cant browse the phpmyadmin and urls?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

NOTE: I am using XAMPP

When I browse localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost/ even the localhost/xampp is not working it just says took too long to respond. I have tried changing the Listen 80 to 8080 in apache(httpd.conf) it didnt solve my problem.

It was working before and then somehow it not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: the control apache in control is running and so is the MySQL. However when I try to run the xampp_start. It restarts the computer I dont know why but it should not restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not port issue as apache is working just it is taking too much time in responding.

If xampp restarts your computer it might be taking too much resources from your PC.  Monitor memory usage and disk usage from task manager.

On windows (specially windows10 ) disk usage makes problem with many application during windows update. If updates are downloaded and not installed; install and rebbot your machine.

If possiible you can try reinstalling XAMPP by taking backup of old configuration files.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it, but it still the same. Also I tried setting it to high priority still the same @SachinPatil4991

Comment: xampp_control works fine but when I run the xampp_start it restarts my pc.

Comment: Anyway how can I reduce the resources it take? @SachinPatil4991